A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or
I am getting error in C#:

This is my code:
public static class EmailService
{
    private static WhistlerLogger _logger = new WhistlerLogger(typeof(EmailService));
    public static bool SendNewPasswordTo(string email, string password)
    {
        try
        {
            using var client = new HttpClient();
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(Main.ServerConfig.MailService.Url);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("text/plain"));
            return  client.GetAsync($"?email={email}&password={password}").Result.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            _logger.WriteError($"SendNewPasswordTo:\n{e}");
            return false;
        }
    }
}

Does anyone knows how to solve it ?
